# 'click' observer in Prototype

Tags: zend-framework, prototypejs, smarty, observer-pattern

I have a page which contains several divs (each with a unique ID and the same class, 'parent'). Underneath each "parent" div, is a div with class "child" and unique ID name -child. This DIV is upon page load empty.

Whenever you click on a parent DIV, the following code is executed.

```
$$('div.parent').each(function(s){
    $(s).observe('click', function(event){
        event.stop();
        var filer = $(s).readAttribute('filer');
        var currentElement = $(s).id;
        var childElement = currentElement + '-children';
        new Ajax.Updater ({success: childElement}, root + '/filers/interfacechildren', {
        parameters: {parentId: currentElement, filer: filer}
        });
    });
});
```

Of course, it's possible that a child node is again a parent ont its own. The response looks like this (Smarty with Zend Framework):

```
{foreach from=$ifaces item=interface}
    <div id="{$interface->name}" filer="{$interface->system_id}" class="parent">{$interface->name}</div>
    <div id="{$interface->name}-children" class="child"></div>
{/foreach}
```

Whenever I click on a "parent" div that is loaded inside a child, nothing happens :( Any suggestions / fixes how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I put the code inside a function, and made it recurse itself onSuccess. That way, when the new parents are loaded with AJAX, the observer function takes into account the new created divs.

Answer (score 0):

Move event.stop() after the Ajax.Updater?

Comment: Even commented out, it's still not working. (but thanks for the suggestion)